# IOS 7 get the wrong status bar height

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I try that the ios 7 will get the wrong height of status bar when the device rotated in swift. I have tested IPad Air (ios 7.0) and IPhone 6 (ios 8.2). It there any solution that can get the correct height of status bar?

Problem Coding(which it get `self.view.bounds.size.width`):

```
let status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Comment: So,what you got from this code and why you say that is wrong

Comment: it get the size of `self.view.bounds.size.width` from `status_height` when i rotate the device. status bar should not big as 1024.

Comment: You need to update the status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height after the rotation was made :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The status bar height will change when rotate,So

**Option 1**

check `statusBarOrientation`first

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.
```

When in **portrait** Use this

```
let status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

When in **landscape** Use this

```
 let status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.width
```

**Option 2**
Converted it to the right coordinate 
In the ViewController you want to get height

```
     var statusBarFrame = self.view.window?.convertRect(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame, fromView: self.view)
     var height = statusBarFrame?.height
```

Comment: the first option is work, but i did not try option 2. Thank you very much for your helping =). I will test it later.